Is it safe to import nuget package with wildcard instead of patch version in production?
I would like to import some third party nuget package into my project. The latest package version is 2.3.4.5
Would it be safe if I import this packages as 2.3.* so that I benefit from patches to be automatically imported? Having major/minor version explicit should prevent any breaking changes?
What is the best practice in this area? I couldn't find any official recommendation by microsoft of nuget.

What do you mean by "automatically imported", exactly?

Also, you are aware that NuGet uses SemVer, right? Provided the packages you're referencing also use SemVer (and are using SemVer correctly) then your question is moot because the most recent nonbreaking package version will always be Restored by VS or by running dotnet restore).

@Dai, "automatically imported" means that with 2.1.* today it will restore 2.1.1 version during build but when I build tomorrow and there is a new patch, it will restore 2.1.2

"Would it be safe if I import this packages as 2.3.* so that I benefit from patches to be automatically imported?" I think this is up to you. The idea of minor version (and even more so, patch version) upgrades is that the are backward compatible as long as the major version is the same. Whether this is completely trustworthy and guaranteed by all published nuget packages all the time ... well, sometimes upgrades do cause problems that are unexpected. But anyway, that's the idea.

Yes, you can either set an explicit version or a limited range "latest" as your referring to. Which is right for your project is very much dependent on your context.
.NET projects allow for NuGet package version ranges, see here. The default is for a specific version (no automatic update), see Visual Studio below.
Examples:
Confidence
If you trust the author of the package to (really) be using Semmantic Versioning and never alter existing functionality on an update, then go for latest within the Major (2.*).
IMO - Most project say they are using Semmantic Version as they use a 3 part version number (sigh) but do not actually comply with Semmantic Versioning nor reliable detect breaking changes. So I do not trust them.
Reproducability
If you work with a testing team they may require a new change review if a package in the build changes. So then reproducability is important to you. That is, if you rebuild that commit next week it will use exactly the same packages.
If you come back in a year to rebuild a prior release would you want all of the packages to automatically be the latest? For that matter what is the source of truth for which packages were used?
Criticality
How critical is your application? Is the convenience of automatically getting latest work the risk? Or is the risk of functional failure lower than the risk of cyber security issues in packages? Do you do automatic builds?
Testing
If you have 100% automated functional tests (not just unit tests) then go for latest as your tests will break the build. No risk!
So if your team uses continuous deployment with 100% ... go for it.
(This is actually the only scenario I would consider always using latest automatically)
Visual Studio (example)
Microsoft's Visual Studio's default behaviour is to record the version you last imported. If there is an update it will appear in the update list but it will not update until you select a new version (unless you change the version to a range).
You can also configure the version to never even offer an update like this:
    <PackageReference Include="Semver" Version="[2.3.0]" />

I have this as a later version breaks my application (to be investigated).
Me
My practice is always use explicit versions and look if there are updates and security issues regularly. On all of my projects package versions are only ever updated manually.

Good points Rob, especially describing the only case where relying on auto update makes sense, i.e. with automatic e2e testing. I was actually curious with such great drawbacks who would ever want to use it.

It is "never safe" to rely on changing upstream version numbers for any dependencies of your source build.
This is, IMHO, totally independent of you using nuget, npm, vcpkg whatever.
You want reproducible builds for your sources - everything else is madness :-) -- given a commit in your repo, it should build the same: today, tomorrow and also next week.
Note that there is more to reproducible builds, also lots of nuances, but the baseline for me is fixed source code and fixed dependencies.
This is the catch-all answer to this. Rob gives a better overview of the nuget specific things.
